# MySQL UNION tables by a single unique field

Tags: mysql, union

I want to UNION tables with identical columns, e.g.:

```
table1
id      var1    var2
1       green   red
2       blue    NULL

table2
id      var1    var2
2       NULL    pink
3       red     blue
```

My result should look like that:

```
id      var1    var2
1       green   red
2       blue    pink
3       red     blue
```

A "normal" UNION creates the following result:

```
id      var1    var2
1       green   red
2       blue    NULL
2       NULL    pink
3       red     blue
```

... with two id = 2 entries, as the two rows with id = 2 are not identical. However, I would like to have only one single row with the id 2.

My current workaround is as follows:

**Step 1**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW temp AS
SELECT id FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id FROM table2;
```

**Step 2**

```
SELECT t1.id, IFNULL(t2.var1, t3.var1) AS var1, IFNULL(t2.var2, t3.var2) AS var2
FROM temp AS t1
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.id;
```

I can't believe that this is the smartest way to solve the problem, as it is such a common one. And it is a real pain in the neck, when the number of tables or variables increases.

Thanks for any smart idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `not exists`:

```
select id, var1, var2
from table1 
union all
select id, var1, var2
from table2 t2
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from table1 t1 
    where t1.id = t2.id
    )
```

---

Here's another with an `outer join / null` check:

```
select id, var1, var2
from table1 
union all
select t2.id, t2.var1, t2.var2
from table2 t2
    left join table1 t1 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.id is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/80dbb0/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, this solution does not combine the fields. id 2 has only the information found in table1.